# hosting event listener app in node js

Tags: node.js, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I have created a sample app based on fabric samples-balance transfer.
I have node sdk files which hosts rest points and chaincode in back end.
I also developed a program which will generate chaincode events from blockchain and written a listener app in node js. I would like to know how to host listener app.

I have app.js that comes up with sample to host all rest apis. how to make this listener app live?

Comment: Why do you want to host the listener separately from your main app? The handler code that you write will be executed when you listen for the event (see : https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/balance-transfer/app/invoke-transaction.js#L101) ? [Not sure if I understood your question correctly.]

Comment: I didn't want to host it as a new app if there is any way I can host it somehow within the same app.. where should I call this listener function within app.js that comes as part of sample node code..
Also, this is a custom chain code event raised in my chain code..

Comment: Just write your logic in a chaincode event handler : https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/EventHub.html#registerChaincodeEvent__anchor. You can write this before calling sendTransaction. See my previous link.